# "unable to verify the first certificate" - How to set up CA certificates in Kong?

Tags: kong

When connecting to my SSL API endpoint on Kong in the browser, I have a secure connection. However when I use any other tool that is not the browser, I get `unable to verify the first certificate`. As I understand it, this is because browsers download the missing CA certs if the server doesn't send them with the domain cert.

I have a root and intermediate CA certs from my provider. I am using docker compose.

I have tried:

- Adding `KONG_SSL_CERT_CAFILE` to docker compose config, with a ca-bundle.crt containing my 3 CA certs.
- Loading all CAs to Kong Manager under "CA Certificates", however these don't appear to do anything (they are not sent when a client interacts with the SSL endpoint.)

Can anyone point me to the documentation/have any tips on how to ensure the CAs are sent from Kong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: in the Certificates tab in Kong Manager, paste in your domain certificate, followed by all the CA certificates (a certificate bundle)

If you don't have the domain cert first, the validation against the key will fail.